# mysql innodb locking for select and update

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a scenario where User A can go to **select** a row and User B can go to **delete or update** that row. Both come to that row at same time.

I am not using transactions. I am using simple select and delete or update queries.

My table db engine is innodb.

What will innodb do in this scenario?

What I think it should hold select query and run delete or update query first but I am not confirmed.

Comment: You have a race condition and whoever comes first will come first.

Comment: yeah I know that but my question is, what if both come at same time. Btw thank for you reply:)

Answer (score 0):

There would always be a microsecond between both (or more) users.

They wouldn't come at the same time.

So the first one wins.

Comment: Is there any document which tells this that both can't come on same time ?

Comment: @murtzagondal - every query is atomic, which means that your data won't change while the query is running. Further reading: [Transactions and Atomic Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html) and [MySQL and the ACID Model](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html)